# Show that lim inf Bn and lim sup Bn equals to a null set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose that ${B_n: n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of disjoint set.

Show that

$$\begin{align}\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}B_n &= \emptyset \text{ and}\\
\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}B_n&= \emptyset \end{align}$$

Where $$\begin{align}\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}B_n &= \{x \mid  x\in B_n \text{ for infinitely many } n\} \text{ and}\\
\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}B_n&= \{x \mid x \notin B_n \text{ for at most finitely many } n\}. \end{align}$$

Can someone help me to solve this?
Since it's a disjoint set, means there is no intersection in the sequence.  So the union of intersection of Bn will be empty set and that's why lim inf  Bn is and empty set too?
Please help me, thanks..

Comment: Do you know whats the meaning of $\limsup, \liminf$ for sets?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Could you possibly look up how to format math stuff. It is easy to find, and simple to use to do basic things. Basically you put the math bit between \$ ... \$ and use some well-known things like a^b (which will come out as $a^b$). [It is mathjax, if you are already familiar with that, or a form of TeX/LaTex if you are familiar with either of those. All 3 are well worth learning these days, irrespective of whether you wish to continue on this site. They are the standard for math.]

Comment: Also formatting like you used above, whilst much better than many newcomers use, is likely to attract downvotes. Those are irrelevant to you now, because "reputation" cannot go negative. But they could matter if you become a regular.

Answer (score 1):

As a given element $x$ cannot be in more than one $B_n$, in particular it can't be in infinitely many, giving both results as the lim sup requires $B_n$ to be in infinitely many, and the lim inf is even stronger requiring it to be in all but finitely many.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, that was expressed in a confusing way. Start again!

As you know already, the default ordering for sequences of sets is inclusion. So in your case $B_{n+1}\subset B_n$.

The problem is the definition of lim sup and lim inf for sequences of sets.

lim sup is defined as the set of all points which belong to infinitely many $B_n$, and lim inf is defined as the set of all points which belong to all but finitely many $B_n$.

Since $k$ belongs to just $k$ of the $B_n$, these two sets are both empty.